# Node.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: node.js, routes, lodash, typeerror

2 weeks into programming and i am building my first web app using nodejs. Everything is working fine except one route which happens to crash my entire app and throws the above error. I have tried solving it but majority of solution for the error are for some specific framework.

Here is node code for reference

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'loremipsum',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/loremipsum", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
})

const loremSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
})

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
const lorem= new mongoose.model("lorem", loremSchema)

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// routes

app.route("/")
.get(function(req,res){
    lorem.find({}, function(err, found){
        res.render("home",{
            posts: found,
        })
    })
});

app.route("/compose")
.get(function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("compose",{
            title: "Be lorem"
        })
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
})
.post(function(req,res){
    const lorem= new lorem({
        title:req.body.postTitle,
        body:req.body.postContent,
    })
    lorem.save()
    res.redirect("/")
});

app.route("/community")
.get(function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("community")
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
});

app.route("/login")
.get(function(req,res){
    res.render("login")
})
.post(function(req,res){
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.login(user, function(err){
        if(!err){
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res, function(){
                res.redirect("/compose");
            })
        }
    })
});

app.route("/signup")
.get(function(req,res){
    res.render("signup")
})
.post(function(req,res){
    User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log("Please, try again...");
            res.redirect("/signup")
        }else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res, function(){
                res.redirect("/compose");
            })
        }
    })
});

app.route("/logout")
.get(function(req,res){
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/:id" ,function(req,res){
    const route = req.params.id;

    lorem.findOne({_id: route}, function(err, foundPost){
            res.render("blog",{
                heading: foundPost.title,
                content: foundPost.body,
            })
    })
})

//listen

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Huston, this is node speaking!!!")
})
```

on adding following route the application crashes

```
app.get("/:id" ,function(req,res){
    const route = req.params.id;

    lorem.findOne({_id: route}, function(err, foundPost){
            res.render("blog",{
                heading: foundPost.title,
                content: foundPost.body,
            })
    })
})
```

Below are code snippet from home.ejs and blog.ejs route.

home.ejs

```
<div class="experiment">
                <div class="col-md-8 card text-left">
                    <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="contents row no-gutters bg-light position-relative">
                                <div class="col-md-8 position-static p-4 pl-md-0">
                                <h5 class="mt-0"><%=post.title%></h5>
                                <p>
                                  <%=post.body.substring(0,150)%>
                                  <a href="/<%=post._id%>">  ...Read more</a>
                                </p>
                                <!-- <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Go somewhere</a> -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-md-0  mb-md-0 p-md-2 unsplash">
                                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628768709954-b141dde9d650?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80" class="w-100" alt="...">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-header">
                              <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Comment</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Share</a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <%})%>                  
            </div>
```

blog.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/head.ejs") -%>

    <h1><%=heading%></h1>
    <p><%=content%></p>

<%- include("partials/foot.ejs") -%>
```

below is the error message.

```
events.js:352
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

any feedback on what i can be doing better is appreciated.

update:
i have applied a bandaid solution to the issue hope it hold, code below;

```
app.route("/toxic/:id")
.get(function(req,res){
    const route = req.params.id;

    lorem.findOne({_id: route}, function(err, foundPost){
        if(!err){
            res.render("blog",{
                heading: foundPost.title,
                content: foundPost.body,
            })
        }else{
            console.log("what the fuck!!")
        }
    })
})
```

the issue is still there but atlest app doesn't crashes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access the "foundPost.title", since foundPost is undefined, it gives the error of cannot read property of undefined. You can check whether any post found from DB or not before accessing property of an object.

Comment: foundPost.title is the query result from lorem.findOne() and there are more then few entries in the database. How do you think I should go about defining foundPost?

Comment: I understand that, have you tried debugging? Are you sure that foundPost is not returning empty or undefined?

Comment: yes, i have console.log the return and title and body are present

Comment: the result for the blog i visible in the "/" but when i try to render the full blog inside the "/blog" route  all the links get broken and application crashes